# How can I create and use custom plugin in Sugar CRM?

Tags: php, plugins, sugarcrm, reusability, sugarbean

I am pretty new to sugar CRM. Can any one suggest me the way to create custom plugin and use that one in Sugar CRM. My task is to make changes to list view in contacts module in sugar CRM.

Comment: Why you are creating plugin if you want to change in list view of contacts?

Comment: Because I have to use same  custom functionality in other part of sugar crm.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make changes to a list view of a core module (contacts) you should create your own files for the customizations required in /custom/modules/Contacts/clients/base/views most likely.

You can use a new .hbs template for the html or add custom logic with a .js controller. You can find additional details here: https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2014/05/28/extending-view-javascript-in-sugarcrm-7/